# Java: help me parse or make sense of this line?

Tags: java, operators

I am having trouble making sense of "publishResultCode", can someone please break down the meaning of that line and the operators?

```
String publishResultCode = value == null ? null : value.toString();
if ("SUCCESS".equals(publishResultCode)) {
  return true;
```

Comment: Read up on the ternary operator and the order of precedence of "=" and "==".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so first let's clear up order of operations

```
String publishResultCode = ((value == null) ? null : value.toString());
```

Now the `==` operator you know is just comparison.  The question probably arises with the `?` `:` operator.  Generally `A ? B : C` means "if `A` is true, return `B`; otherwise return `C`".  And lastly, of course `=` is assignment.

So:  If `value` is `null`, set `publishResultCode` to `null`; but if `value` is not `null`, set `publishResultCode` to the value returned by calling `value.toString()`.

Comment: thanks so much. These operators make code concise but I just need to get used to them

Answer (score 2):

```
if(value==null)
    publishResultCode=null;

else publishResultCode=value.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

This sets `String publishResultCode` as null if `value` is null and sets it as `value` if it isn't. The code then returns if `publishResultsCode` is the word "SUCCESS".
The question mark after `value==null` is basically an if-else statement,if `value ==null` then `publishResultCode = null` ,else `publishResultCode = value`.

Answer (score 1):

I think deep down you need just this :D

```
return value != null && "SUCCESS".equals(value.toString());
```

Comment: Maybe.  He didn't show what happens if `"SUCCESS".equals(value.toString());` returns false.  Maybe it doesn't immediately return.  And if it does, `return "SUCCESS".equals(value.toString());` would suffice, as this will already be false if `value` is null

Comment: Maybe +1. Also dont we wanna avoid NullPointer and return false when value is null? (If that is what suppose to happen)

Comment: Hm.  I was looking at what `"SUCCESS".equals()` would do and neglected that a method call was required.  Yeah, the extra check is worth while